# Is it possible to add a global render callback for a given template engine in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stenciljs

I am trying to pre-hydrate Stencil.js components on an Express server to improve client-side experience. I've found that doing this in the callback of `res.render()` once the template has been compiled to HTML works well, but I would rather not update all the instances of this function's use.

Is there a way of using a global callback for this template engine?

```js
import * as express from "express";
import * as cons from "consolidate";

export const server = express();
const engine = "pug";
server.engine(engine, cons[engine]);
server.set("view engine", engine);

const transformHtml = html => ...

server.get("/test", (req, res, next) => {
    res.render("test", (err, html) => {
        if (err) { throw err; }
        res.send(transformHtml(html));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can override the res.render function

```js
server.use((req, res, next) => {
  var oldRender = res.render;
  res.render = function (...) {
    //... custom code and can call the original res.render with oldRender(...)
  }
});
```

Comment: I believe this answer should work but for whatever reason did not work in my case. I ended up solving my problem by extending the response on the express server object:
`server.response.renderAndHydrate = function(...) { this.render(...) };`